# with python how to find a string from all files in a directory and subfloders

Tags: python, os.walk

i am trying to find which files contains "RunInstances" from aws cloudtrail logs, with grep i could easily run this command to find out:
grep -r "RunInstances" *

but i want to try to use python, i tried os.walk, and something is wrong:

```
john@john-HP-ProBook-4411s:~/Downloads$ python
Python 2.7.12 (default, Nov 20 2017, 18:23:56)
[GCC 5.4.0 20160609] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import os
>>> for path,dir,file in os.walk("."):
...     for fileNames in file:
...             if fileNames.endswith("json"):
...                     fileName = str(os.path.join(path,dir,file))
...                     print(fileName)
...
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 4, in <module>
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/posixpath.py", line 68, in join
    if b.startswith('/'):
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'startswith'
>>>
```

could you please offer me with some suggestions please?

Comment: These are some very confusing variable names. You’re using `file` for a list of many file names, and then `fileNames` for each individual file name from that list. And I think that’s directly leading to the confusion that caused you to write code that looks right but is actually nonsense.

Comment: As a side note, calling `str` on the result of `os.path.join` is a bad idea. You’re using Python 2, which means it already _is_ a `str`, so that’s just useless and slightly misleading. And if you tried to run this code in Python 3, it would be actively wrong—it probably already is a `str`, but if not, you’d be asking it to convert a name from the file system using the default i/o encoding instead of the file system encoding; if there is a difference, you’ve chosen the wrong one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is here:

```
fileName = str(os.path.join(path,dir,file))
```

You’re trying to join a path, a list of names, and a list of names into a path. That doesn’t make any sense. If you look at the sample code you copied, I’m pretty sure it’s joining the path and a single dir or file from the list, not a path plus both lists.

In particular, you probably want to `os.path.join(path, fileNames)`.

That may seem confusing, but that’s because your variable names are confusing. Passing `file` to `join` fails because `file` is, despite the name, a whole list of file names, while passing `fileNames` would work because, again despite the name, it’s just a single file name.

Answer (score 0):

`file` in the for statement is a list of all files in in the directory os.walk() is in. If there is only one file it is a list of one element.

Answer (score 0):

```
import os
for path,dir,file in os.walk("."):
    for fileNames in file:
        if fileNames.endswith("json"):
            fileName = str(os.path.join(path,fileNames))
            print(fileName)
```

You were close, just `dir` is a list and so ist `file`. `fileNames` on the other hand is just a string. And you cant join a path with a list as one argument.

Comment: thanks Mrlenny, your answer is correct and helped me out, but unfortunately i can not select 2 best answers :( but thank you anyway!